# Where to get an easily parseable list of country names and their calling codes

Tags: country-codes, mobile-country-code

Where can I find an easily parseable list of the names of all countries and their calling codes (i.e. their mobile country codes).

For example

United States of America,1

United Kingdom,44

Sultanate of Oman,968  etc.

Comment: search for "csv country list" (or "sql country list" if you want a database script). There's oodles of them out there.

Comment: @WimOmbelets Among those oodles, can you point me to any One?

Comment: The research is the fun part! I wouldn't want to take all your fun.